# I can upload PDF on AWS S3from my lambda function but when I download it locally I cant open it

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I upload my pdf on S3 succesfully but when I download it it doesnt open. This is my code

```
      request = multipartFormDataService.getDocumentRequest(contentType, event.getBody(), stringwithstuff);
```

And then

```
  public DocumentRequest getDocumentRequest(String contentType, String body, String logger) {
try {
  var multipartFormDataService = new MultipartFormDataService();
  byte[] boundary = multipartFormDataService.getBoundary(contentType);
  String encoding = multipartFormDataService.getCharacterEncoding(contentType);
  InputStream inputStream = multipartFormDataService.getContent(contentType, body);

  MultipartStream multipartStream = new MultipartStream(inputStream, boundary, 1000, null);
  ParameterParser parser = new ParameterParser();
  parser.setLowerCaseNames(true);
  var request = new DocumentRequest();

  boolean nextPart = multipartStream.skipPreamble();
  while (nextPart) {
    String header = multipartStream.readHeaders();
    String name = parser.parse(header, ';').get("name");

    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    multipartStream.readBodyData(output);
    if ("pdf".equals(name) || "\\\"pdf\\\"".equals(name)) {
      byte[] pdfBytes = output.toByteArray();
      logger += "PDF Headers: " + header + "\n";
      logger += "Size of PDF from multipart: " + pdfBytes.length + "\n";
      request.setPdfContent(pdfBytes);

    } else {
      
    }

    nextPart = multipartStream.readBoundary();
  }

  return request;
} catch (IOException e) {

}
return null;
```

}

I get response 200 and the document does get uploaded at S3. But Its always a bit bigger in size than the original so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I assume the way I process it inside the getDocumentRequest method?

This is my S3 upload method

```
public void uploadPdfToS3(String bucketName, String key, byte[] pdfContent) {
String s3ObjectKey = key + ".pdf";
ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
metadata.setContentType("application/pdf");
metadata.setContentLength(pdfContent.length);
InputStream contentStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfContent);
s3Encryption.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, s3ObjectKey, contentStream, metadata));
```

}

Do you have any suggestions as to what might be wrong or any alternative ways to do it? I still need to use the AmazonS3EncryptionV2 library.

Thanks in advance